# Python: inline vs variable definition

Tags: python, variables

Given a list `a`, I'm looking for a way to programmatically find out if a list element is defined inline, i.e.,

```
a = [123]
```

or by reference, i.e.,

```
number = 123
a = [number]
```

and if the latter, what the variable name is.

Any hints?

Comment: What is the practical application of knowing this information?

Comment: You can't do this. Why do you want to do this? I can't think of any practical reason to do so. This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166789)?

Comment: The context is quite complex which is why I haven't gone into detail here. Essentially it evolves around a domain-specific Python to C++ transpiler. A list is given, and I need to find out if the classes still need to be defined in C++ or if they are already there (aka if defined previously aka if a variable exists).

Comment: Are you looking for `sys.getrefcount`? It won't be perfect, especially for small integers like 123 (which are preallocated in a cache), but might work for other kinds of objects.

Comment: why doesn't your lexer distinguish between number literals, string literals and identifiers already?

Answer (score 4):

Walk the [abstract syntax tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) of the code you're translating. One will be a Num and the other will be a Name. It is not possible to do this based on the list itself, as objects in general have no logs of how they came to be and in this example an optimizer may have changed the method in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If `number` is still available to you, you could compare like so:

`id(number) == id(a[0])`

Depending on your further requirements, though, this may not be all you need.

Comment: Are you sure this works? Because `id(2) == id(2)` is `True`, as is `a=2; id(a) == id(2)`. I see no reason it should, since numbers always point to the same object (IIRC it's different for strings, but even there short strings may refer to the same underlying object).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - Hence my comment: "Depending on your further requirements, though, this may not be all you need." Without more detail from the OP, I cannot ensure this will or will not be sufficient.

Comment: But it always returns `True` as far as I can see? So in what situation would this work then?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker In the case where they can reference and compare to the `number` variable.

Comment: I'm confused? If I do: `number=42; id(number) == id(42)`  it evaluates to `True`. So when would it be `False`? What code do I need to write for that?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It wouldn't with your example and that is not the point. Since I can only assume the requirements of the OP (very little are provided) it may be sufficient for them to compare the variable `number` with the value of `a[0]`. Unless more detail is provided to demonstrate a more complex solution is needed, this is still one possible to solution.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, and without accessing source, there is absolutely no way of knowing whether the reference came to being inline or was assigned to a variable first. Basically you can pretend that `sys.getrefcount()` could tell the truth:

```
% python3
Python 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class Foo():
...     pass
... 
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(Foo())
1
>>> bar = Foo()
>>> sys.getrefcount(bar)
2
```

But small integers and constant strings will have shared references and things fall down:

```
>>> sys.getrefcount('a')
6
>>> sys.getrefcount(1)
758
```

And then you'd have the case that value was created within a function but returned for there and that original reference was lost, and what not...

---

The only really usable way that I know of is to walk the abstract syntax tree of the source code.